# Could not find class 'com.parse.ParseObject$30', referenced from method com.parse.ParseObject.fetchInBackground

Tags: android, eclipse, push-notification

please help me.i folowed this tutorial http://youtu.be/HxO3t7ZN4k4    . but on run time i get this in logcat.  thanks in advance. i amvery new to it. i want to get push notification.i hv done nothing in build path. help me

Answer (score 0):

i think you forget to add this code to your onCreate in application class:

```
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
```